# How to run Griffon application successfully?

Tags: maven, groovy, griffon

I am new to Griffon 2 Framework. I am going to create new project using Griffon 2. I am going with http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html reference. I am able to create new project successfully but when I run project using maven then project clean install Success but not run. I get following output on "**mvn clean install**"

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.griffon:sample:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target
[INFO] [jacoco:prepare-agent {execution: prepare-agent}]
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/piyush/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.3.201502191951/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.3.201502191951-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [build-helper:add-source {execution: add-source}]
[INFO] Source directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/griffon-app/conf added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/griffon-app/controllers added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/griffon-app/models added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/griffon-app/services added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/griffon-app/views added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/griffon-app/lifecycle added.
[INFO] [processor:process {execution: default}]
[WARNING] No processors specified. Using default discovery mechanism.
[INFO] [build-helper:add-resource {execution: add-resource}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/classes
[INFO] [gplus:compile {execution: default}]
[ERROR] Unable to determine Groovy version.  Is Groovy declared as a dependency?
[ERROR] Unable to determine Groovy version.  Is Groovy declared as a dependency?
[ERROR] Unable to determine Groovy version.  Is Groovy declared as a dependency?
[ERROR] Unable to determine Groovy version.  Is Groovy declared as a dependency?
[ERROR] Your Groovy version (null) doesn't support compilation.  The minimum version of Groovy required is 1.5.0.  Skipping compiling.
[WARNING] DEPRECATED [tasks]: Use target instead
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: process-resources}]
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/test-classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/classes
     [copy] Copying 8 files to /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/classes
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/classes
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/test-classes
[INFO] [gplus:testCompile {execution: default}]
[INFO] No sources specified for compilation.  Skipping.
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.gt.SignUpControllerTest
[2015-07-04 15:19:12,515] [main] INFO  org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultApplicationBootstrapper - Griffon 2.3.0
[2015-07-04 15:19:12,516] [main] INFO  org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultApplicationBootstrapper - Build: 2015-06-02T23:14:51.218+0200
[2015-07-04 15:19:12,516] [main] INFO  org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultApplicationBootstrapper - JVM: 1.7.0_80 (Oracle Corporation 24.80-b11)
[2015-07-04 15:19:12,516] [main] INFO  org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultApplicationBootstrapper - OS: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic amd64
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.236 sec - in com.gt.SignUpControllerTest

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/sample-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [checkstyle:checkstyle {execution: run-checkstyle}]
[INFO] 
[INFO] There are 1 checkstyle errors.
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing /home/piyush/Documents/GriffonExample/sample/target/sample-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/piyush/.m2/repository/com/griffon/sample/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/sample-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 04 15:19:19 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 74M/369M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but when I run project with "mvn Prun" I get following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Invalid task 'Prun': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 04 15:22:59 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/74M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any one help me run Griffon 2 project?

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -Prun` like it says in the documentation?

Comment: No worries, maybe delete this question? :-D  Have fun!

Comment: @tim_yates but how to package and distribute?